# for loop in countAndSay function keeps returning blank string after array join

Tags: javascript

I am working on the countAndSay leetcode question. I think my logic is correct, and I'm certain my code is almost there, but I keep getting a blank output on my return statement. I'm struggling to find where my code is causing this string to be blank. Could someone help me out?

The count-and-say sequence is a sequence of digit strings defined by the recursive formula:

countAndSay(1) = "1"
countAndSay(n) is the way you would "say" the digit string from countAndSay(n-1), which is then converted into a different digit string.
To determine how you "say" a digit string, split it into the minimal number of groups so that each group is a contiguous section all of the same character. Then for each group, say the number of characters, then say the character. To convert the saying into a digit string, replace the counts with a number and concatenate every saying.

```js
/**
 * @param {number} n
 * @return {string}
 */
var countAndSay = function(n) {
    sayString = "1";
    sayArray = [1];
    root = 0;
    previousRoot = 1;
    count = 0;

    //begin master loop that creates sayString out of sayArray, run through it n times
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        //loop through the sayString as many times as there are characters to create a sayArray
        for (let i = 0; i < sayString.length; i++) {

            //take the first digit in the string call it root
            root = sayString[i];

            //if root equals previous root (1 on first loop),
            if (root == previousRoot) {
                // increase count variable by 1
                count++;
            }

            // else add the count to the sayArray, add the new root value to the array, set count to 0
            else {
                sayArray.push(count);
                sayArray.push(root);
                count = 0;
            }

            //change previous root to root so we can check its value next time through the loop
            previousRoot = root;
        }
        //make the new sayString a concatination of the sayArray
        sayString = sayArray.join("");
        //set the sayArray to empty so we can start popolating it again during the loop
        sayArray = [];
    }
    //after weve ran the major loop n times, return sayString
    return sayString;
};

console.log(countAndSay(4));
```

Comment: Now is a great time to start using your browser's debugging tools.  When you step through your logic in a debugger, which specific operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: I would definitely use different iterators in your loops; using `i` for both is confusing and will overwrite each other.

Comment: @user1599011 confusing yes but they won't overwrite each other

Comment: @David thanks, I will check out some tutorials and start using dev tools